# Converting time duration in string to seconds

Tags: ruby

I need to convert duration which I am getting to seconds. How do I do it in ruby?? I am getting string as

> 1hr 10min

I need to convert this into seconds i.e. `1*60*60 + 10*60 = 4200 seconds`

Is there any function to do it in ruby? Or do I need to use regular expresion and extract both and convert hour to seconds and mins to seconds. What would be the best way to achieve it.

Answer (score 6):

Use [Chronic Duration](https://github.com/hpoydar/chronic_duration), e.g.,

```
irb> require "chronic_duration"
irb> ChronicDuration.parse("1hr 10min")
=> 4200
```

This also lets you go the other way, handle a wide variety of input, etc.

```
irb > ChronicDuration.output(4200)
=> "1 hr 10 mins"
irb > ChronicDuration.output(4200, format: :short)
=> "1h 10m"
irb > ChronicDuration.output(1299600)
=> "15 days 1 hr"
irb > ChronicDuration.output(1299600, weeks: true)
=> "2 wks 1 day 1 hr"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a lib to do this but you could do something like this:

```
h = "1hr 10min".split(" ")[0].split("hr")[0].to_i*60*60 # => 3600
m = "1hr 10min".split(" ")[1].split("min")[0].to_i*60   # => 600
h+m #=> 4200
```

but maybe there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own function:

```
def time_to_duration(t)
    r = %r{^(\d+)hr (\d+)min}
    t.match(r)
    return $1.to_i*60*60 + $2.to_i*60
end

d = '1hr 10min'
time_to_duration(d)

#=> 4200
```

Answer (score 0):

The following method will handle `2hr`, `1hr 20min`, `1hr 10min 5sec`, `20min 5sec`:

```
names = {'hr'=>3600,'min'=>60}

'1hr 10min'.scan(/(\d+)\s*(\w+)/).reduce(0) { |memo, val| 
  memo += (names[val[1]] || 1) * val[0].to_i 
}.last
#⇒ 4200

'1hr 5sec'.scan(/(\d+)\s*(\w+)/).reduce(0) { |memo, val| 
  memo += (names[val[1]] || 1) * val[0].to_i 
}.last
#⇒ 3605
```

Hope it helps.